# randomAccessFile.readLine() returns null after many uses even though not reaching EOF?

Tags: java, file, io, random-access, randomaccessfile

I have a file with 10K lines.

I read it in chunks of 200 lines.

I have a problem that after 5600 lines (chunk 28), `randomAccessFile.readLine()` returns `null`.

however, if i start reading from chunk 29 it reads another chunk and stops ( return null).

I force reading from chunk 30, and again - it reads one chunk and stops.

this is my code:

```
private void addRequestsToBuffer(int fromChunkId, List<String> requests) {
    String line;
    while (requests.size() < chunkSizeInLines) {

        if ((line = readNextLine()) != null) {
            return;
        }
        int httpPosition = line.indexOf("http");
        int index = fromChunkId * chunkSizeInLines + requests.size();
        requests.add(index + ") " + line.substring(httpPosition));
    }


}

private String readNextLine() {
    String line;
    try {
        line = randomAccessFile.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            System.out.println("randomAccessFile.readLine() returned null");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return line;
}


@Override
public List<String> getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId(int fromChunkId) {
    List<String> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    int linesNum = 0;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fromChunkId; i++) {
            while ((linesNum < chunkSizeInLines) && (randomAccessFile.readLine()) != null) {
                linesNum++;
            }
            linesNum = 0;
        }
        addRequestsToBuffer(fromChunkId, requests);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return requests;
}
```

what can cause this? `randomAccessFile` time out?

Comment: Are you calling `getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId` without resetting the position in the `RandomAccessFile`? If so, that would cause the problem. It would help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `addRequestsToBuffer` has an erroneous check for `!= null`.

Comment: Btw, the way your `readNextLine` is implemented is often considered bad coding style.

Comment: Why are you re-reading the file anyway? Is there another process appending to the file while your program runs?

Comment: `RandomAccessFile.readLine()` is behaving correctly. You have a bug in *your code*. Probably the one that *Hanno Binder* pointed out, but possibly another.

Comment: @HannoBinder (1) `erroneous check for != null` how would you check otherwise? (2) `considered bad coding style` - how would you write this? (3) `Why are you re-reading the file anyway?` I need to handle a 10K lines input file. So I use map-reduce to process it.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please write an answer. i'll mark it as correct

Comment: `!= null` should be `== null` to make any sense.

Comment: Re: bad style - Converting a checked exception into a `RuntimeException` is almost always bad. I figure the `println` is only there for debugging, otherwise I'd put it somewhere up the call stack, as I would do for the exception handling. But don't mind these minor suggestions while we haven't fixed the actual functional issue.

Comment: 10K lines don't seem a lot to me. Can't you process them all in one go? - Holding them all in memory should pose no problem on anything with more than 128MB of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId` you're skipping the specified number of chunks, without "rewinding" the `RandomAccessFile` to the start. So for example, if you call:

```
getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId(0);
getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId(1);
getNextRequestsChunkStartingChunkId(2);
```

you'll actually read:

- Chunk 0 (leaving the stream at the start of chunk 1)
- Chunk 2 (leaving the stream at the start of chunk 3)
- Chunk 5 (leaving the stream at the start of chunk 6)

Options:

- Read the chunks sequentially, without skipping anything
- Rewind at the start of the method

Unfortunately you can't use `seek` for this, because your chunks aren't equally sized, in terms of bytes.